# Draw squares within a php forms

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to php coding and in my project I would like to draw squares around the square-shaped php forms I made.

However, I have difficulties in doing so... As you can see the the code below, I was testing and try to draw a square with a div below but it is not showing... Can someone please suggest what have I done wrong please?

Cheers,
Karen

```
<?php
$to = 'sender@email.com';

$subject = 'HTML Form in HTML Email';

$headers = "From: receiver@email.com\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";

$message = '<html><body>';


$message .='<div style="width:10px; height:10px; border:1px black !important;">';
$message .='</div>';


$message .= '<form action="http://mysite/process.php" method="post" name="emailCrossword" target="_blank">';

$crossword = array();
$crossword = 6;

for ($i=0; $i<=$crossword.length; $i++){
    echo
    $message .= '<input type="text" style="width: 13px; text-transform:capitalize;" placeholder="text-align:center;" name="commentText" maxlength="1"></input>';
}

$message .= '<br/>';
$message .= '<br/>';
$message .= '<input type="submit" name="crossword" value="Submit your crossword" />&nbsp;</form>';

$message .= '</body></html>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! You won't get much help posting a follow up question in comments - the best strategy is to ask a new question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your css shorthand for the border is wrong:

```
border:1px black !important;
```

Should be:

```
border:1px solid black !important;
```

For a solid line obviously...

Comment: Hello, I am actually trying to create a crossword puzzle with php, where the php square-shaped forms would be where the users could type in alphabets and the other squares would be static squares around them!

Comment: @KarenChan You might want to put your input elements inside these boxes.

Comment: A crossword puzzle. Interesting. And everyone is saying how evil it is to use tables in HTML nowadays  <grin>

Comment: @Mawg Yes I have a lot of trouble... the alignment and spacing between the forms and boxes are so hard to control...

Comment: To be honest, I think that this is one time that a table is definitely called for. That would make your life very easy

Comment: @Mawg as this gets sent by mail it is probably the only real option.